# jQuery and SVG with custom attributes in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, svg

I have some SVG elements on my web page that I want to access with jQuery. The SVG elements have a couple of custom data-attributes attached to them, and I want to use that in the jQuery selector to get the correct elements. My problem is that the custom attribute selector does not work in Chrome, while it works in IE9 and Firefox. Here is an example of an SVG element:

```
<rect width="75" data-myAttribute="someValue"></rect>
```

And this is the javascript I would use to obtain all elements with the custom attribute set:

```
$('rect[data-myAttribute]');
```

So what happens is that the statement returns 0 elements in Chrome, while it returns all X elements in Firefox and IE. Using "standard" attributes in the selector does however seem to work in all browsers. This statement would for instance return all the elements correctly in all browsers:

```
$('rect[width]');
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening, and what I could do to use custom attributes on SVG elements  in a jQuery selector? I use custom data-attributes because the SVG elements does not have an ID or class that I can use instead.

Note: The SVG elements in this specific case is created by the HighCharts javascript library, but I guess that should not matter. I use jQuery version 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must
>   be prefixed with 'data-'. It should not contain any uppercase letters.

Try this -

```
<rect id='r' width="75" data-value="someValue">d</rect> 

$('rect[data-value]');   // select element with data-value attribute

$('rect').data('value'); // read attribute value
```

[jsFiddle working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/RFtgD/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But that does not seem do return anything for me. The data function is defined, but the result object is just undefined (also for standard attributes like "width"). Do I need a newer jQuery version or something?

Comment: See this working-- i just changed the data attribute name -- http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/RFtgD/

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I'm after. I edited your fiddle to highlight the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/84YrN/ 
Here it should only get the jQuery elements a and c (because b does not have the data-value attribute). It does however log all three rectangles

Comment: Ok so you want to access only those `rect` that have `data-value` attribute ?  -- http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/84YrN/1/

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Your newest fiddle does however still output the wrong result. It outputs "a b c" even though b does not have the value attribute

Comment: No.. It output's on the console not on the body...document still show's `abc` but see console it will show `ac`

Comment: Yes, of course it ouputs to the console, my bad! :) I see it now. So the strange thing is then why this is not how it behaves in my code. As you can see from the question, this is what I originally had, but when I run it in chrome, the jQuery selector does not return any elements. I tested with using the "id" attribute instead of a custom data-attribute, and then it worked fine! This is really strange..

Comment: you had an upperCase letter in your data attribute `myAttribute` .. that is why it didn't work..